# (Python) How to override list's method python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, methods, overriding

well, i want to add method in list.
So, i made new child class like this.

```
class list(list):
    def findAll(self,position):
        data = []
        for i in range(len(self)):
            if(self[i] == position):
                data.append(i)
        return data

k = list()
k.append(1)
k.append(2)
k.append(3)
k.append(4)
print(k.findAll(10))
```

but i want to make code like this.

```
class list(list):
    def findAll(self,position):
        data = []
        for i in range(len(self)):
            if(self[i] == position):
                data.append(i)
        return data

k = [10,1,2,3,4,5,10,10,10,10,10] #when i make list, i want use '[' and ']'

print(k.findAll(10))#it occur AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

how can i make this?
when i make list, i want use '[' and ']'

i tried this code

```
class list(list):
    def findAll(self,position):
        data = []
        for i in range(len(self)):
            if(self[i] == position):
                data.append(i)
        return data

k = [10,1,2,3,4,5,10,10,10,10,10]
k = list(k)
print(k.findAll(10))
```

Comment: It is better to make your own class which inherits from `list` rather than to try to change `list` itself. This makes the code easier to understand. Python programmers already know what a `list` is, so if you would change its meaning then anyone reading your code would be in danger of misunderstanding anything which used your version of `list`.

Comment: Your code seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a child class shouldn't have the same name as the parent, especially when it's a standard class, it can lead to lots of confusion down the road.
you could use the same name, but it should be in a particular package, so when it's used, to be sure it's not confused with the other one.

Another thing here, when you want to use your list class, you need to instantiate it.
With this `k = [10,1,2,3,4,5,10,10,10,10,10]`you instantiate the standard list, also with `k = list(k)' because you use the same name, instead of package.class to distinguish, also because in your class you have no overwritten method that takes a list as argument, no conversion method etc.

The answer already given by the other user should be ok, but so you understand what is what and why I wrote this

Answer (score 0):

## You can't override built in type's method.

You can create a new class, that "extends" class "list" (inheritance).

```
class ExtendedList(list):
  def find_all(self, num):
    return [i for i in range(len(self)) if self[i] == num]

k = ExtendedList([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3])
print(k.find_all(3))
# [2, 3, 4, 6]
```